# Youtube JavaScript API i can't make it responsive and centered

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

I'm trying to implement a Youtube video and get the video centered and fully responsive and I got it working but I couldn't get it to work fully responsively.

```js
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;

  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('vid', {
          Width: '100%',
          Height: '100%',
          videoId: '6JK-nkvs-UY'
      });
  }
```

```css
 body {
     margin: 0px;
 }
 .openFrame {
     display: table;
     position: absolute;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: yellow;
     background-position: center;
     background-size: cover;
 }
 .main {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
 }
 .inner {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     text-align: center;
 }
 #cta {
     width: 85%;
     height: 6em;
     background-color:black;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: top center;
     background-size: contain;
     cursor: pointer;
 }
 .videoCon {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 9999999;
 }
 #vid {
     width: 90%;
     max-height: 100%;
     margin: auto;
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
 }
 #bottom {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     cursor: pointer;
```

```html
<div class="openFrame">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="videoCon">
                <div id="vid"></div>
                <div class="inner" id="cta"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It works fine on the certain screen sizes but I couldn't get it to work fully responsively.

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: What exactly are you want? explain this `fully responsive` more clear please.

Comment: i mean that video is full responsive from desktop to mobile

Comment: I know what is fully responsive. But the video size change based on screen width. So what's the problem.